# Custom Notification Recipients to New Places with Page Reference Navigation

Tags: visual-workflow, notification

In release Winter'21 was introduced new Target option for Custom Notifications ([see here](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter21/release-notes/rn_mobile_notifications_pageref.htm)).
I would like to have a specific Community page as Target Page Reference. Still, I can't figure out the format I need to put into the Target Page Reference attribute on Custom Notification action. Every format I try makes the flow fail with the error `Invalid parameter value for: targetPageRef`. I would like to navigate to the Community Home page. Any suggestion?
[image]

Comment: I've had a similar issue and have tried the following: 1) a string with a partial URL, 2) An apex instance of a  pagereference with the partial URL, 3) the getURL() method on that pagereference.

Comment: @Bigears did any of that work?

Comment: No, it didn't. I was just adding my experience. Apologies for not being clearer. However, the answer below worked for me and I've been able to navigate as I need to pages within the community.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems that `targetPageRef` is expecting lightning [pageReference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.reference_page_reference_type) types in a string format, so if you pass the otherwise json as a string, like the following:
`"{"type": "standard__objectPage","attributes": {"objectApiName": "Task","actionName": "list"},"state":{"filterName":"Recent"}}"`

you'll be redirected to the listview of the recent Task records when clicking the notification.

Comment: I would like to navigate to the community Home page. Do you have any suggestion on how to achieve that?

Comment: @mascot to reference a community home, page the type `comm__namedPage` must be used, followed by the "Home" value in the `name` attribute.
So the string `"{"type": "comm__namedPage","attributes": {"name": "Home"}}"` should cover your use case.

Comment: Hi @zigzig, I'm struggling to get this to work here https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/331750/what-is-the-syntax-of-the-string-set-via-settargetpageref-in-the-new-apex-messag via the new Apex API trying just the JSON string. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Keith for answer [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/334365/45062) For redirecting in communities you can use the below code.

```
private final Map<String, Object> communityPageRef = new Map<String, Object>{
    'type' => 'comm__namedPage',
    'attributes' => new Map<String, Object>{
        'pageName' => 'home'
    }
};

customNotification.setTargetPageRef(JSON.serialize(communityPageRef));
```

If you are on a console tab in lightning and you want to navigate to home page then use this.

```
private final Map<String, Object> lightningPageRef = new Map<String, Object>{
    'type' => 'standard__namedPage',
    'attributes' => new Map<String, Object>{
        'pageName' => 'home'
    }
};
customNotification.setTargetPageRef(JSON.serialize(lightningPageRef));
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured I'd add this as nobody online seem to say it regarding where you need to put that in flow. You can paste that code into a text template variable (make sure it's set as plain text), then use that variable in the send custom notification action under Target Page Reference.