# Bell icon in communities: syntax of the setTargetPageRef string?

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, community, pagereference, notification

The Winter '21 [CustomNotification Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.228.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_Messaging_CustomNotification.htm) offers two ways to set the target navigated to when the message displayed under the "bell" icon is clicked:

- `setTargetId(Id targetId)` - Sets the target record of the custom notification
- `setTargetPageRef(String pageRef)` - Sets the target page of the custom notification

What can the `pageRef` string contain? I'd like to use these notifications in a community (i.e. the bell notifications) where the page to go to would need to be set via that value. So far no value I have set results in the notification appearing; the notification does appear when the `targetId` is set.

**PS**

Based on Shamina's comment/link I tried passing this JSON (without the line feeds; this is one of the [LWC PageReference Types](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/reference_page_reference_type)) using API 50 and got:

> Invalid parameter value for: targetPageRef

for:

```
{
    "state":{
        "eventId":"a053F000004MTJOQA4"
    },
    "attributes":{
        "name":"event-details"
    },
    "type":"comm__namedPage"
}
```

I also can't get this to work with e.g. the `standard__webPage` type either. But see Jeferson's answer where some of the `standard__*` types work.

What am I missing here? Are only some PageReference types supported?

**PPS**

Can this be set by any means e.g. via a [flow or the REST API](https://andyinthecloud.com/2019/06/30/getting-your-users-attention-with-custom-notifications/)? I tried the REST API approach, and got:

> Unexpected data type for targetPageRef: expected String

with JSON data for the `targetPageRef` and:

> Invalid parameter value for: targetPageRef

with JSON data serialized to a string for the `targetPageRef`.

Note that the "Send Custom Notifications" permission must be granted to avoid this error:

> Unsupported action type: CUSTOM_NOTIFICATION_ACTION

Comment: With regards to Case #40382890, support did cover that the pageRef parameter should be following the format as described in [PageReference Types](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.reference_page_reference_type) (Like Shamina pointed out). They are going to get the documentation updated to reflect that. The support case didn't cover using the notifications in communities.

Comment: Thanks for the update @DanielBallinger. I do see that state is not documented for comm__namedPage (but is for others) so will try removing that, though I do need to inject a [query string parameter](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.use_navigate_add_params_url) somehow. I'll also try with the `c__` prefix.

Comment: I even tried using `JSONGenerator` but nothing works in `setTargetPageRef` from anonymous apex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leaving out the "state" value at least results in the notification being posted. But as described in [A click on a bell icon notification in Communities (now called Digital Experiences) doesn't navigate](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/334321/a-click-on-a-bell-icon-notification-in-communities-now-called-digital-experienc), I couldn't get the "comm__namedPage" approach to navigate on a click. So instead I'm using "standard__webPage" and that does work.

Answer (score 5):

I could see it working (outside of Communities, I have not tried that part yet) with the following scenarios:

- Named Page Type (type = `standard__namedPage`): quite limited but useful.
- Item Page Type (type = `standard__navItemPage`): navigates to tabs.
- Record Page Type (type = `standard__recordPage`): navigates to a records, in modes such as view, edit (my example), and clone.

Conclusion so far: it seems that the comment from Bartheleway, `setTargetPageRef` using JSON format syntax is correct, based on my tests, at least.

Note: thanks for the references shared, that [LWC PageReference Types](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/reference_page_reference_type) & [CustomNotification Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.228.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_Messaging_CustomNotification.htm) references served as the basis of the tests I made.

Code to send a notification to the current user:

```java
// Named Page Type. Drives to Home Page.
/*String addressTest = 
'' +
'    {' +
'        type: \'standard__namedPage\', ' +
'        attributes: {' +
'            pageName: \'home\'' +
'        }'+
'   }'+
'';*/

// Item Page Type. Drives to a custom tab named NotificationTab.
/*String addressTest = 
'' +
'    {' +
'        type: \'standard__navItemPage\', ' +
'        attributes: {' +
'            apiName: \'NotificationTab\'' +
'        }'+
'   }'+
'';*/

// Record Page Type. Drives to the edit page for the given Account record id.
String addressTest = 
'' +
'{' +
'       type: \'standard__recordPage\',' +
'       attributes: {' +
'           recordId: \'0012X000022RUSLQA4\',' +
'           objectApiName: \'Account\',' +
'           actionName: \'edit\'' +
'       }' +
'}';

// Get the Id for our custom notification type
CustomNotificationType notificationType = 
    [SELECT Id, DeveloperName 
        FROM CustomNotificationType 
        WHERE DeveloperName = 'Custom_Notification'];

// Create a new custom notification
Messaging.CustomNotification notification = new Messaging.CustomNotification();
notification.setTitle('Apex Custom Notification');
notification.setBody('The notifications are coming from INSIDE the Apex!');
notification.setNotificationTypeId(notificationType.Id);
notification.setTargetPageRef(addressTest);

// Actually send the notification
try {
    notification.send(new Set<String>{UserInfo.getUserId()});
}
catch (Exception e) {
    System.debug('Problem sending notification: ' + e.getMessage());
}
```